# How to highlight specific domain in Google search results?

Tags: javascript, firefox-addon, greasemonkey

Below greasemonkey script highlight defined domains.
Ex: my search query is book and my domain is amazon. If there is more than zero results for this domain, it highlights that div.

But it is not working. Because it designed for old Google design about four years ago. I try to change something but nothing.

**Script source** : [Locate Multiple Domains Highlights](http://lifehacker.com/5708110/locate-multiple-domains-highlights-your-favorite-sites-in-google-search-results)

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name           Locate Multiple Domains in Search Results
// @filename       multiple-domains.user.js
// @author         Alex Hall
// @homepage       http://www.devseo.co.uk
// @namespace      http://www.devseo.co.uk/blog/view/greasemonkey-script
// @version        1.0
// @description    Locate specific domains easily within the results of a Google, Yahoo!, or Bing Search
// @include        http://www.google.com/search*
// @include        http://google.com/search*
// @include        http://www.google.com/#*
// @include        http://google.com/#*
// ==/UserScript==

//***********************BEGIN CONFIGURATION**********************//
// Set the array of sites you wish to locate (without www is best) - syntax [['mydomain.com', '#color'], ['mydomain2.com', '#color']];
// Set the color variable to the background color you wish to use to highlight your domain (defaults to light red)
var sites = [
        ['domainxyz.com', '#FFCC66'],
        ['www.domainxyz.com', '#C2D9EF'],
];

var siteLen = sites.length;
var numNot = 0;

//************************END CONFIGURATION***********************//

//*******************DO NOT EDIT PAST THIS LINE*******************//
//****************UNLESS YOU KNOW WHAT YOU'RE DOING***************//
setTimeout(startItOff, 1000);
function startItOff()
{
        var all_links = document.getElementsByTagName('cite');
        var linkLen = all_links.length;
        if (location.hostname.indexOf("google.com")!=-1) {
            for (i=0; i<linkLen; i++) {
                if (all_links[i].className!='l') { continue; }
                var href = all_links[i].value;
                        if(all_links[i].parentNode.tagName.toLowerCase() === 'div'){
                                numNot++;
                        }
            }
            for (i=0; i<linkLen; i++) {
                if (all_links[i].className!='l') { continue; }
                var href = all_links[i].getAttribute('href');

                for(j=0;j<siteLen;j++){
                   if (href.indexOf(sites[j][0])==-1) { continue; }
                   var result=all_links[i].parentNode.parentNode;
                   result.style.backgroundColor=sites[j][1];
                   result.style.overflow='hidden';
                   result.style.width='740px';

                           var listingNum = all_links[i].getAttribute('onmousedown');
                           listingNum = listingNum.split(',');
                           listingNum = listingNum[4].split('\'');
                           listingNum = listingNum[1];
                           var resultDiv = document.createElement('div');
                           result.appendChild(resultDiv);
                           resultDiv.style.cssText = 'float: right;font-size:16px;margin:0 5px 5px 0;background: #FFF;padding: 5px;';
                           resultDiv.innerHTML = 'Result ' + (listingNum - numNot);
                }
            }
        }
}
```

I changed something on this part of script, still it is not working

```
    var all_links = document.getElementsByTagName('cite');
    var linkLen = all_links.length;
    if (location.hostname.indexOf("google.com")!=-1) {
        for (i=0; i<linkLen; i++) {
            if (all_links[i].className!='l') { continue; }
            var href = all_links[i].value;
                    if(all_links[i].parentNode.tagName.toLowerCase() === 'div'){
                            numNot++;
                    }
        }
```

Comment: You're going to have to be a bit more specific than that.

Comment: it is very clear i think

Comment: What have you tried? What's working? What's not? What do you need? It seems to be a simple copy-paste of the code from your link. We're not here to do it for you. We're here to help you achieve it yourself.

Comment: try `h3` instead of `h4` for the parentNode

Comment: Probably because the `href`s are linkwrapped and otherwise corrupted (i.e. monetized).  The little green elements with the url's in cleartext (often shortened w. ellipses, but domain name (almost?) always included) have tag `cite` and class `_Rm`.  It looks like in your revision you're gathering `cite` tags, which is good.  At this point I would replace `all_links[i].getAttribute('href')` with `all_links[i].textContent`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are going to want to use use JQuery. And it is a very simple script, if I understand correctly. Note: the jQuery Google has installed does not work properly, so you definitely need your own, no matter what you do.

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name           Google Search Domain Highlighter
// @author         Wisnoskij
// @homepage       https://openuserjs.org/users/wisnoskij
// @namespace      https://openuserjs.org/users/wisnoskij
// @version        1.0
// @description    Locate specific domains easily within the results of a Google Search
// @include        /https?://(www\.)?google\.[^/]*/search[^/]*/
// @require        http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js
// ==/UserScript==
var sites = {
    'stackoverflow.com': '#FFCC66',
    'tutorialspoint.com': '#C2D9EF',
    'css-tricks.com': '#CCFF66'
};
var numHL = 0;

$('._Rm').each(highlight);
function highlight(index, element){
    try{
    var node = $(element);
    var site = node.text();

    site = getDomain(site);
    if(sites[site]){
        node.closest('.rc').css('background-color', sites[site]);
        return;
    }
    site = removeWWW(site);
    if(sites[site]){
        node.closest('.rc').css('background-color', sites[site]);
        return;
    }
    }catch(er){}
 }

function getDomain(url){
    var tmp = url.indexOf('://');
    if(tmp > -1){
        url = url.substring(tmp+3);
    }
    url = url.match(/^[^/]*/)[0];
    tmp = url.indexOf(' › ');
    if(tmp > -1){
        url = url.substring(0, tmp);
    }
    return(url);
}
function removeWWW(url){
    var tmp = url.indexOf('.');
    if(tmp > -1){
        url = url.substring(tmp+1);
    }
    return(url);
}
```

Fully functional, working script.

Comment: If I wrong notify me please. Will I delete all code except meta block lines than paste your solution?

Comment: @hakiko Updated with whole script.

Comment: Ok thank you very much. But when link has breadcrumb how can handle also them? Like this: www.example.com › Brands › Adidas

Comment: You need to give me an example. Because it works for me. (https://www.google.ca/search?q=url+javascript). Correctly finds all three stackoverflow domains.

Comment: on your example link look css-tricks.com it has breadcrumb please change your domain array or add css-tricks.com

Comment: Amazing. You save my time. Regards

Comment: Awesome of you to spoon feed the guy. I feel people learn the most from that because it example code tailored to a person, so the person obviously tried to do it themselves, and when you give them this they look at it and learn from it. :)